# How to number rows after a multi row paste operation

Tags: excel, vba, excel-365

I have a number of data sources to bring into Excel for analysis. I start each data set by pasting a one line header on Row 1 starting in Column B that will go to Column "X" (each source has a different number of columns). Column A Row 1 I manually type a reference code for the page the data was found.

Each page of the original data set contains multiple lines of data. Each line is formatted the same.

I can manually paste the data into Excel starting on Column B, then go to Column A by the first new row and put the page number then auto fill down or drag to the end of that set.

However I would like some VBA code to auto fill the page number based on an incremental value increase of 1.

Not all paste operations will have the same number of rows but each set is the same page. For example page 5 might be 9 rows that need to be labeled page 5, then page 6 might have 25 rows.

This code allows me to paste my header Row into Row 1 starting in Cell B1 and type in A1.

I can then paste my rows of data into Excel into cell B2 and Excel understands that the paste operation is multiple rows and labels A2-A# with the value 1 based on the number of rows I inserted.

This is where I am stuck. If I paste the next set of data into B# (the next blank row below where my last set ended) Excel still puts a 1 next to all the new rows instead of a 2.

I would like the code to verify the value used in Column A for the last set then increase by an increment of 1 for the next set.

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim lastRowB As Long
    Dim firstBlankCellA As Range
    Dim firstBlankCellB As Range
    
    Set rng = Range("B:B")
    
    ' Exit if the row being edited is row 1 (Title Row)
    If Target.Row = 1 Then Exit Sub
    
    ' Find the last row with data in column B
    lastRowB = Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    
    ' Find the next blank cell in column A
    Set firstBlankCellA = Cells(lastRowB + 1, "A")
    
    ' Find the next blank cell in column B
    Set firstBlankCellB = Cells(lastRowB + 1, "B")
    
    If Not Intersect(Target, rng) Is Nothing Then
        ' If the cell two rows above the first blank cell in Column A exists and is preceded by a number,
        ' use the next numerical value for all rows with new text
        If firstBlankCellA.Row > 2 And IsNumeric(firstBlankCellA.Offset(-2, 0).Value) Then
            i = firstBlankCellA.Offset(-2, 0).Value + 1
        Else
            i = 1
        End If
        
        ' Add the numerical value to each row with new text
        For Each cell In Target.Cells
            If cell.Value <> "" And cell.Offset(0, -1).Value = "" Then
                cell.Offset(0, -1).Value = i
            End If
        Next cell
        
        ' Select the first blank cell in column A for the next paste job
        If Target.Rows.Count > 1 Then
            i = i + Target.Rows.Count - 1
        End If
        firstBlankCellA.Offset(1, 0).Select
        firstBlankCellB.Offset(1, 0).Select
        
        ' Select the first blank cell in column B
        Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Select
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Just curious, is the process something like this ? You manually copy a range of data on certain sheet, paste it to the the the first blank cell in column B of a sheet (which has the Worksheet_Change sub), then soon after you paste, it trigger the macro to fill the page number (of the sheet which was copied) to column A, "align" with the rows of pasted data in column B ? Example : you activate **sheet3**, copy B2:C6 (**5 rows of data**), activate the saheet which has the sheet_change sub, paste to B10  (the first blank cell in column B). Expected result, **A10:A14** value **3** ? Please CMIIW.

Comment: The sources being copied are not in Excel. They are in a tabular format but it is not Excel due to the original source the data can not be downloaded it has to be highlighted and copied then pasted into Excel.

Comment: If the sources which are copied are not Excel, I don't think Excel has the ability to know that the manually pasted data is coming from what page number. The one that I can think of, soon after you pasted the data, prompt an input box for user to fill the page number. So, whatever random page which is copied, Excel know the page number from the user input, so then Excel put that user input value to column A "align" to how many rows of the pasted data in column B. Without prompt, the only thing I can think of is just do a number increment where cell A2 value will always start with number 1.

Answer (score 0):

This does not find the next blank cell in column A

```
' Find the next blank cell in column A
Set firstBlankCellA = Cells(lastRowB + 1, "A")
```

Try replacing the first part of your code with this:

```
Set rng = Range("B:B")

' Exit if the row being edited is row 1 (Title Row)
If Target.Row = 1 Then Exit Sub

' Find the last row with data in column A
lastRowA = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

' Find the last row with data in column B
lastRowB = Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

' Find the next blank cell in column A
Set firstBlankCellA = Cells(lastRowA + 1, "A")

' Find the next blank cell in column B
Set firstBlankCellB = Cells(lastRowB + 1, "B")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim r As Integer, num As Integer
Application.EnableEvents = False
If Target.Column = 2 Then
    r = Target.Rows.Count
    If Application.CountA(Target) = 0 And Target.Row > 1 Then
        Target.Resize(r, 1).Offset(0, -1).ClearContents
    Else
        With Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)
            If .Row = 1 Then num = 1 Else num = .Value + 1
            .Offset(1, 0).Resize(r, 1).Value = num
        End With
    End If
End If
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

First it check, if the change happen in column B then it will do the operation, if not then it just exit the sub.

The operation:
it get how many rows of the target which is changed into r variable.

Than it check if the countA of the target = 0 (meaning a user clear the content of row/rows in column B) then it will also clear the content in column A as many as the rows which is cleared the content in column B.

If the countA is not 0 (meaning, a user paste a data into column B) then it will first check if that is the "first time" data in the sheet by checking if the last row with data in column A is 1 then put 1 to num variable, if not row 1 then add that last row value + 1 to num variable. Then finaly it fill column A with num value as many as the r value (the rows count of the target).

The copied data is from a table in a website page in the image below:
[image]

If the expected result is not an increment number, but random number which only "god" knows the manually pasted data to the sheet is coming from what page number of outside source, then just have the num variable as an input box. Something like `num = application.inputbox("please type the page number of the pasted data")` and remove  some unnecessary line of codes.

[image]